# Window.postMessage generates Uncaught TypeError: no access

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to connect a chrome extension to twitter using following code:

```
//open new window    
var newWindow = window.open('https://domain.io/connect/twitter/', 'Connecting', "");


setInterval(() => {

  console.log(newWindow) // print empty object
  newWindow.postMessage('msg', 'https://domain.io/'); 

}, 5000);
```

It works well as a HTML page but when I bring it to the chrome extension it make "Uncaught TypeError: no access" and newWindow became an empty object.

In some stages it works before being redirect to twitter.com even after returning to domain.io it doesn't work. I use Vue.js and above code is located inside mounted method.

Comment: Where exactly does that code run? Is it a content script? Then you can use chrome extension messaging.

Comment: It's an inject script trying to receive token code from domain.io. Has chrome extension messaging any specific advantage?

Comment: Chrome [page-to-extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) or the normal content script messaging is predictable and not used by the site whereas abusing postMessage may break a site that expects a certain type of the message so sending a string will cause the unsuspecting site code to fail.

Comment: If you're not using `"externally_connectable"` and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`, per the docs linked by wOxxOm, you are better off with a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) than `window.postMessage()`. Custom events are only received by listeners which are listening for the specific name of the event, whereas listeners for `window.postMessage()` receive the messages send from all sources. This can mean that you receive messages from unexpected sources and your messages can confuse in-page listeners designed to only handle expected in-page messages.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].